# expect with shell for multiple taksks of cloud foundry CLI

Tags: shell, expect, cloud-foundry

I have a task of creating docker container and working through its lifecycle. To automate it I am using shell with expect as cloud foundry cli is interactive
below is my code:

```
         #!/usr/bin/expect -f
         spawn cf login -a <api url>
         #set timeout 30
         expect "Email>"
         send "email id\r"
         expect "Password>"
         send "passw0rd"
         expect -exact ">"
         send "2\r"
```

Till above line, the code is working as expected.From the last 2 lines above it can be seen that, I have to enter 2 at '>'. After this the $ prompt like below is shown which ends with '$':

```
        expect "trishal@trishal-VirtualBox:~/PycharmProjects/Trishal-     VC/containers$"
         send "cf ic init"
```

Now, after coming on '$' prompt, I expect the code to accept 'cf ic init' which is a command to initialize the work space. Its not accepting, the output stays at '$' prompt itself and doesn't proceed. I had also tried below:

```
         expect -exact "$"
         send "cf ic init"
```

no luck 
screen remains at
trishal@trishal-VirtualBox:~/PycharmProjects/Trishal-VC/containers$

Answer (score 0):

`expect -exact "$"` will work for sure to match the literal dollar.  All `send` commands should be sent with `\r` which represents the 'Enter' key. After the last command, add `expect eof` if your program will complete at that time and no further interaction required.